# Why are slices endindex not the endindex

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

I just started to learn python and I've comes to slices of strings.

When I type

```
suitcase = ["sunglasses", "hat", "passport", "laptop", "suit", "shoes"]
print suitcase[0:1]
```

I expect it to print `['sunglasses', 'hat]`, but I get `['sunglasses']`. From what I've read it's `aList[beginIndex:endIndex]`, but from my experience it's more like `aList[beginIndex:endIndex+1]` to get the index you which to have last.

Can someone explain why it's like this? I can't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: how would you expect to select the first elem then? I think this is pretty much the reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slices in Python are defined as inclusive/exclusive, i.e., the first item you want, followed by the first item you *don't* want.

I don't know specifically why they did it this way, but it's consistent with how `range()` works, and also works well with `len()` (that is, a slice of a whole container `x` is `[0:len(x)]`); this also plays well with negative slices: `x[-1]` is `x[len(x)-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange): "The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j."

Answer (score 2):

The best argument in my opinion is that you can get the number of elements returned by the slice using `endIndex - startIndex`.

This is also closely related to the built-in `range()` function.  If two arguments are used they are interpreted as a start and stop index, but if only one is used then it is the stop index and the start index is set to `0`.  So `range(5)` gives a list with 5 elements.  If slices worked they way you think they should then `range()` would probably have the same behavior, and `range(5)` returning 6 elements would be pretty confusing.